# Recursively Totaling File Content

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a Python script that will take a directory as input and look through that directory recursively and output the file names and their sizes to a file. At the end it totals the entirety of the directory. The output is okay and fits what I need but all file sizes are being listed at 4096 when I run this code on the `/var` directory. Below is code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

#print usage for input directory and accepts input

print("Example: /home/cn")
input_file = raw_input("Enter the name of the directory: ")

#prints usage for output file and accepts input

print("Example: /home/cn/Desktop/output_test.txt")
output_file = raw_input("Enter the name of the output file: ")

#opens output file for writing, sets variable for directory size to 0

of = open(output_file, "w")
start_path = input_file
total_size = 0

#loops recursively, calculates directory size

for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(start_path):
    of.write(format(path))
    of.write(" " + str(os.path.getsize(path)) + "\n")
    for file in files:
        fstat=os.stat(os.path.join(path,file))
        size = os.stat(path).st_size
        total_size = total_size + size

#writes output to file

of.write("\n" + "Directory: " + input_file + "\n")
of.write("The total size of the directory is: " + str(total_size))
```

And also a screenshot of the output file when this is run on the `/var` directory:

[image: /var directory output]

Comment: So you're pretty much doing what `du` does?  Maybe just use `du`?

Comment: You are printing only directory sizes. The size of a directory does not take into account the content.

Comment: Also, did you notice that you are adding up only the results of the last iteration?

Comment: I know this is what du does but I am attempting to write scripts in Python so I can learn it - thanks for the response!                                                   
                                                                                                                 I knew something was wrong with how I was adding it up, so  that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: What's recursive about your code—I don't see anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not producing the file path at all. You need to join the file name with the current path in order to get the file path and only then get the size of the file in question:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(path))  # just to cover symlinks
    of.write("{} {}\n".format(full_path, os.path.getsize(full_path)))  # not a real size!
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(full_path, file)  # get the file path
        size = os.stat(file_path).st_size  # get the actual file stats
        of.write(" {} {}\n".format(file_path, size))  # write the file path and size
        total_size += size
```

Comment: in the inner loop, should be file_path, not full_path, to be printed

Answer (score -2):

It is because you are just checking for root path size.

Instead try below code

```
for (path,dirs,files) in os.walk(start_path):
    of.write(format(path))
    of.write(" " + str(os.path.getsize(path)) + "\n")
    for dir in dirs:
        dir_path = os.path.join(path, dir)
        of.write(format(dir_path))
        of.write(" " + str(os.path.getsize(dir_path)) + "\n")
```

Try this !

Comment: This doesn't list the files but directories so it doesn't do what OP needs, plus getting sizes off of directories will get you the size of directory record, not the size of the directory content. And finally, you're not adding anything to the `total_size` at the end so the stats will return `0` anyway.